# JQuery Events Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function changeScreenFromOptions() {
    if (screen == 1) {
        $('#screen').empty();
        $('#screen').append("<br><br>");
        $('#screen').append("<label for='file' class='textStyle'>Filename (hint:Write The Fullpath of The File):</label>");
        $('#screen').append("<input type='text' name='file' id='upload'><br>");
        $('#screen').append("<input type='submit' id='SubmitFile' class='textStyle' value='Submit'>");

        $('#SubmitFile').click(function() {

            SheetPath = document.getElementById('upload').value;
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    $('#screen').empty();
                    $('.listContainer').empty();
                    var groupData = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    var res = eval("(" + groupData + ")");
                    WorksheetListSize = res.length;
                    //alert(WorksheetListSize);

                    for (var i = 0; i < WorksheetListSize; i++) {
                        $('#screen').append("<div id='worksheet" + i + "' class='worksheet'>" + res[i] + "</div>");
                        $('.listContainer').append("<div id='worksheet" + i + "' class='listComponent'>" + res[i] + "</div>");
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function() {

                        $('.listComponent').click(function() {

                            alert("here");

                        });
                    });

                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getWorkSheets.php?pather=" + SheetPath, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        });
    } else {
        $('#screen').empty();
        $('#screen').append("<p class='Optionfontstyle'>Under Construction</p>");
    }
}
```

This is My JavaScript Code About Changing Screen According to a Specific Selection Tool, The Problem is When I try to make click event to class (ListComponent), it's not responding to me, I'm Beginner in JQuery and JS, I Think it's a scope problem but I Can't Understand it !!

Comment: Remove the `$(document).ready` which is only fire once when your DOM is ready.

Comment: FYI: you can chain your jQuery methods when using the same selector, i.e.: `$('#screen').empty().append("<br><br>")...`

Comment: It's Some Kind Of Separating Code From Each Other to be clear and easier to be edited

Answer (score 0):

try below code..remove document.ready from the code and take out $('.listComponent').click(function()  code from submit click event because both click events are different and will be called when respective button will be clicked

```
  function changeScreenFromOptions() {
        if (screen == 1) {
            $('#screen').empty();
            $('#screen').append("<br><br>");
            $('#screen').append("<label for='file' class='textStyle'>Filename (hint:Write The Fullpath of The File):</label>");
            $('#screen').append("<input type='text' name='file' id='upload'><br>");
            $('#screen').append("<input type='submit' id='SubmitFile' class='textStyle' value='Submit'>");

            $('#SubmitFile').click(function() {

                SheetPath = document.getElementById('upload').value;
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        $('#screen').empty();
                        $('.listContainer').empty();
                        var groupData = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        var res = eval("(" + groupData + ")");
                        WorksheetListSize = res.length;
                        //alert(WorksheetListSize);

                        for (var i = 0; i < WorksheetListSize; i++) {
                            $('#screen').append("<div id='worksheet" + i + "' class='worksheet'>" + res[i] + "</div>");
                            $('.listContainer').append("<div id='worksheet" + i + "' class='listComponent'>" + res[i] + "</div>");
                        }
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "getWorkSheets.php?pather=" + SheetPath, true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            });
             $('.listComponent').click(function() {

                                alert("here");

                            });

        } else {
            $('#screen').empty();
            $('#screen').append("<p class='Optionfontstyle'>Under Construction</p>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing Changed ... When i Press on '.listComponent' nothing happen !!